# Выбор элемента select при помощи jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

У меня такая проблема:
Есть Select:

```
 <select id="make" name="make">
    <option value="0"> ---------------------- </option>
    <option value="Mercedec">Mercedec</option>
    <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>                                       
    </select>
```

И я прописал js код в консоль:

```
$("#make [value='Mazda']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Возвращет нужный элемент option, selected="selected", но я смотрю на список, а выбран все равно первый option(value=0).

```
$("#make [value='Mazda']").attr("selected", "");
```

Тот же результат, помогите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы визуально был выбран элемент с value='Mazda', естественно он должен быть выбран и по настоящему.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что это некая особенность реализации JS в Chrome. Ваш код вполне успешно выполняется под IE (10-ая версия) и Firefox (23-я). А вот в Chrome (28-я) происходят описанные вами проблемы. В Opera не проверял. 
Так или иначе, с помощью вот такого чудо-костыля:

```
var val = text = 'Mazda';
$("select option[value=" + val + "]").attr('selected', 'true').text(text);
```

добытого мною исключительно методом тыка, это можно обойти. Не могу сказать, за счет чего это работает (люди, лучше знакомые с JS, думаю, смогут это как-то объяснить). Вероятно, это действительно адов костыль, тем не менее, может сойти за временное решение

Comment: Костылей никаких не нужно! 

    $("#make option[value='Mazda']").prop("selected", true);

P.S. Зачем булевое значение в кавычки?

Comment: >P.S. Зачем булевое значение в кавычки?

не более, чем опечатка

Comment: правильный ответ здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/568815/2872

Answer (score 7):

В текущих версиях jQuery для смены `option` в `select` и выбора `checkbox` надо использовать метод `.prop()`

```
$('select option[value="Mazda"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Данный метод изменяет свойство javascript объекта соответствующего `option` и не добавляет атрибуты, то есть в разметке ничего не изменится. Хотя добавление атрибута пока, что работает с `option` (проверил в Opera), но не работает с `checkbox`.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте

```
$('#make').val('Mazda')
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения таеих вещей как selected и checked, надо использовать prop, а не attr.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#make").val("Mazda").change()
```

Answer (score 0):

Туго понял вопрос но возможно

```
$("#make option[value='Mazda']").val('Mazda').attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Лично я предпочитаю следующий метод однострочник:

```
$("select").val("").trigger("chosen:updated")
```

Во всех браузерах должно работать.
Соответственно вместо пустой строки нужно использовать текст первого `option`'а, но как правило дефолтный `option` должен быть пустым, а не содержать 0 и т.п.

Соответственно подставляя значение любого `option`'а его можно выбрать.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно применять атрибут `selected` к элементу `option`:

```
 $("#make>option[value='Mazda']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#make").val("Mazda");
```

Это все.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Верно. Но [точно такому же ответу](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430655/178988) уже 2 года.

Comment: Все так, но простой и верный ответ вытеснен сомнительными решениями. В то время как поднять правильно решение для ищущих и страждущих мне не позволяет система.