# Выбор нужного option в select (js / jquery). Проблемы с отображением в хроме

Tags: javascript, jquery

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается функция, в которую передается 2 аргумента - набор option'ов и номер нужного option'а

```
function changeSelectedItem(elems, item_num){
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){      
        if(elems.eq(i).attr("selected") != undefined)
            elems.eq(i).removeAttr("selected");             
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++){      
        if(j == item_num)
            elems.eq(j).attr("selected", "selected");           
    }
}
```

Задача - выставить у элемента с переданным номером атрибут select (чтобы он выбрался). В первом цикле я удаляю у всех элементов атрибут select, если он есть. Во втором цикле добавляю этот атрибут лишь элементу с нужным номером.

Проблема - корректно работает во всех браузерах, кроме хрома. В коде при нажатии F12 (консоль, вкладка Elements) атрибуты меняются так, как надо, но в самом  браузере option меняется через раз или через два. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина такого поведения хрома и как это исправить. Возможно, есть какой-то метод принудительного выбора option'a и его установки в select'e

Comment: В документации по JQuery метод [attr](http://api.jquery.com/ATTR/) не используется для изменения свойств checked, selected или disabled. Это написано прямо в самом начале документации. Для работы с ними следует использовать [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) с параметрами true/false. В противном случае поведение может быть непредсказуемым.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже тоже нашел решение. Тут подробно все описано - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245920/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-select-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-jquery

Comment: @andrew357 По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (если это не полный дубликат другого вопроса). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Решение: вместо `.attr()` надо использовать метод `.prop()`

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос. Вот пример с использованием JQuery.

```js
function changeSelectedItem(elems, item_num) {
  elems.find('option').removeAttr("selected");
  elems.prop('selectedIndex', item_num);
}

changeSelectedItem($("#selecttest"), 3); //индекс 3 === 4 элементу по тому, что идет нумерация их с 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selecttest">
  <option>test 1</option>
  <option selected>test 2</option>
  <option>test 3</option>
  <option>test 4</option>
</select>
```