# Почему программный выбор опции в select срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: jquery, ui

Почему программный выбор опции в select срабатывает только один раз? Код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#default").attr('selected', 'selected');
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $("select option:contains('two')").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option>----------</option>
    <option id="default">one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>                                      
</select>
    
<button>set two</button>
```

Теперь теряюсь в догадках... В чем может быть причина?

Comment: для селекта можно `val(...)` использовать для установки, получения значения

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за подсказку, я бы еще долго мучился. все делал по ответу опытного участника http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245920/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-select-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-jquery

Comment: тот вопрос/ответ слишком старый, несколько версий jquery сменилось уже, отличия в них довольно значительные

Comment: @Grundy , как оказалось метод `val` не всегда отрабатывает , меняешь его на метод `prop` и он справляется. видимо они не одинаковы. с вот такой строкой "02.20.11.114 Бревна кедровые для распиловки и строгания" и подключенным плагином select2 метод `val` не справился.

Comment: в плагине select2 есть свои методы для установки значения

Comment: Да есть но и они с такой строкой почему то не работают. В чем причина не знаю, видимо с пробелами не корректно работает.

Comment: чтобы сказать _почему_ не заработало, нужно как минимум видеть [mcve]

Comment: самодостаточный работает

Comment: имелось ввиду пример, демонстрирующий ошибку

Comment: проект большой. как создать такую же ситуацию я не знаю. что является причиной не ясно. в песочнице все работает просто отлично, переносишь в боевой код и упс не работает. но стоит его заменить на метод `prop` и все проблемы исчезают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С версии 1.6 `.attr()` работает непосредственно с атрибутом элемента и в некоторых случаях результат не совсем ожидаемый, желательно использовать `.prop`...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#default").prop('selected', true);
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $("select option:contains('two')").prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option>----------</option>
    <option id="default">one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>                                      
</select>
    
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: @perfect с версии 1.6 .attr() работает непосредственно с атрибутом элемента и в некоторых случаях результат не совсем ожидаемый, желательно использовать .prop...

Answer (score 1):

Для присваивания свойств типа `checked`, `delected`, `disabled` надо использовать `prop`, а не `attr`. В любом случае, для выбора значения в `select` лучше использовать `val`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#default").prop('selected', true);
});

$("button").click(function(){
  $("select").val('two');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>----------</option>
  <option id="default">one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>                                      
</select>

<button>set two</button>
```